# Update column value on inner join of two tables with where clause

Tags: mysql

Here is the MySQL query:

```
SELECT `wp_fcfebce_postmeta`.`post_id`,
        `wp_fcfebce_postmeta`.*
FROM `wp_fcfebce_posts`,`wp_fcfebce_postmeta`
WHERE `wp_fcfebce_postmeta`.`post_id`=`wp_fcfebce_posts`.`ID`
        AND `wp_fcfebce_posts`.`post_date_gmt` > '2018-05-20 00:00:00'
        AND `wp_fcfebce_posts`.`post_date_gmt` < '2018-05-20 23:59:59'
        AND `wp_fcfebce_postmeta`.`meta_key`='_wp_attached_file'
```

I want to update the contens of the `meta_value` column in the `wp_fcfebce_postmeta` table, which have the condition from join `wp_fcfebce_posts` and `wp_fcfebce_postmeta` tables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the same logic as in your select, but applied to an update, you may try the following:

```
UPDATE wp_fcfebce_postmeta t1
INNER JOIN wp_fcfebce_posts t2
    ON t1.post_id = t2.ID
SET t1.meta_value = 'some_value'
WHERE
    t2.post_date_gmt >= '2018-05-20' AND
    t2.post_date_gmt < '2018-05-21' AND
    t1.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file';
```

Note that I reworded the date restrictions in your `WHERE` clause.